# How to remove special chars form string in hive

Tags: java, regex, string, hadoop, hive

Hi guys i m completely new to hive ..

[image: i have amount column in table]

1)i am trying to remove dollar sign from amount but its not working am using reg-ex extract.

2)and also want count of amount between 0- 99,100-199 and so on.

Comment: what did you try? and what were the results?

Comment: i tried but not working  SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(OrderAmount, '^((?![0-9]).)*$', '')
FROM
order;  am getting output : $21.00 
$56.40 
$78.00 
$14.00 
$54.00 
$58.00 
.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your cell has strings of format ($ddd.dd).. I would simply replace `$` with `''`

EX:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(OrderAmount, '\\$', '')
```

For counting between range of 100 you can do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order GROUP BY floor(float(REGEXP_REPLACE(OrderAmount, '\\$', ''))/100);
```

Comment: i found out that we need to escape escape characters also in hive syntax.. please see updated answer

Comment: thanks  its working , but m stuck , now am trying to  count of amount between 0- 99,100-199 and so on , so how will  i can i do this, can you please guide, as per my understanding the output in is string

Comment: what i tried   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order GROUP BY float(REGEXP_REPLACE(OrderAmount, '\\$', ''));  m getting count of every amount like if 100 is present two time its return 2

Comment: , but i want count of Amount between 0-99, 100-199 and so on

Comment: try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order GROUP BY (float(REGEXP_REPLACE(OrderAmount, '\\$', '')/100));`
 `

Comment: thanks but still getting same output, can we use BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99.0 ??? i also tried this       select COUNT(*) from order
 WHERE float(regexp_replace(substr(OrderAmount, 2, length(OrderAmount)), ',', '')) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99.0; but no output shown